# What does this symbol in intellij mean? (brown box with 9)

Tags: intellij-idea

[image: image with icon]

I have a bunch of groovy files, one of them has this icon infront of it. What does it represent?

--

Checked if its added as favorite. Its not part of any favorites group.

[image: not favorite]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you've added a `Bookmark`.

Use ctrl-9 to toggle it or shift-f11 to manage.

Comment: Not sure if I follow it correctly, but I dont have an option of Alt + F2, Ref (https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/intellij-idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf)

Comment: Also I right clicked on file and tried to add it to favorites, it currently not a favorite..

Comment: Sorry my mistake. its a Bookmark. (been a long day so far... memory like mush!)

Comment: Aha! thanks! Yup, Shift + F11 (Show bookmarks) and then removing it did the trick.